# cypher - load multiple csv files

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher

I have many csv files with names `0_0.csv , 0_1.csv , 0_2.csv , ... , 1_0.csv , 1_1.csv , ... , z_17.csv`.

I wanted to know how can I import them in a loop or something ?

Also I wanted to know am I doing it good ? ( each file is 50MB and whole files size is about 100GB )

This is my code :

```
create index on :name(v)
create index on :value(v)    

USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///0_0.txt" AS csv
FIELDTERMINATOR ',' 
MERGE (n:name {v:csv.name}) 
MERGE (m:value {v:csv.value})
CREATE (n)-[:kind {v:csv.kind}]->(m)
```

Comment: How many distinct `name` and `value` entries result from the 100GB? How does your source data get created? Is pre-processing an option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could handle multiple files by constructing a file name. Unfortunately this seems to break when using the `USING PERIODIC COMMIT` query hint so it won't be a good option for you.  You could create a script to wrap it up and send the commands to `bin/cypher-shell` though.

```
UNWIND ['0','1','z'] as outer
UNWIND range(0,17) as inner
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///'+ outer +'_' + toString(inner) + '.csv' AS csv
FIELDTERMINATOR ',' 
MERGE (n:name {v:csv.name}) 
MERGE (m:value {v:csv.value})
CREATE (n)-[:kind {v:csv.kind}]->(m)
```

As far as your actual load query goes. Do you `name` and `value` nodes come up multiple times in the files? If they are unique, you would be better off loading the the data in multiple passes. Load the nodes first without the indexes; then add the indexes once the nodes are loaded; and then do the relationships as the last step.

Using `CREATE` for the `:kind` relationship will result in multiple relationships even if it is the same value for `csv.kind`. You might want to use `MERGE` instead if that is the case.

For 100 GB of data though if you are starting with an empty database and are looking for speed, I would take a look at using `bin/neo4j-admin import`.

Comment: Thanks so much. Yes, They come up multiple times. I can't create them before applying the index. for kind there are no duplicate values and that's why I have used the create command. I couldn't find neo4j-admin file in neo4j folder !? ( I have installed the Community Edition )

Comment: `neo4j-admin` should be there in the `bin/` directory of recent versions of the community edition. Older versions would include `neo4j-import` but they use the same syntax for loading. Using these tools will load an empty database file directly and will be much faster.  You would have to pre-process your data though so you have a file of nodes and a file of relationships.  It is orders of magnitude faster though so if you have lots of data, you can load an empty database and speed it a concern it would be the way to go.